# Flash to be ported to iOS 7 and 8

Tags: ios, flash, adobe, ios8, ios7.1

Can we port still port Flash developed applications to iOS 7 and 8?

Before we've tried porting an application from flash to iOS 6 with the help of adobe air mobile. Does this still work now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can develop applications for iOS with Adobe AIR. (on iOS8 works too)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I found some new apps that have flash too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to answer my question for iOS 7, yet I'm not sure for iOS 8. 
But AIR should have an update for the iOS 8. most likely.
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/puffin-web-browser/id406239138?mt=8